# Pentaho reporting connectionFactory has new method added but no description

Tags: reporting, pentaho

I am in process of upgrading my pentaho reporting from 3.6.1 to 3.8.0 in my web application. when I updated all necessary jar files, I got one compilation error in one of my class which implements `ConnectionProvider`. following is my class.

```
public class DataSourceConnectionProvider implements ConnectionProvider
{

....

}
```

The error is saying that my class should implement `getConnectionHash()` method as it is defined in `ConnectionProvider` interface. but It was not there in 3.6.1 version. so I am bit confused why they have added it and how to implement it in my class.

Comment: I just noted that this new method in ConnectionProvider interface was not there till 3.7.0 release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method returns a object that is comparable and hashable and is used during the caching of datasources. It allows us to build some sort of key to detect changes in the connection definition while many reports run within the same JVM.

The cache implementation itself does not know any of the details of the various datasources and the "ConnectionHash" allows us keep result-sets separate.

My basic implementation of it simply returns a ArrayList with all relevant connection properties added to it.

Simple example how and where it is needed:

Imagine you have a JDBC datasource that connects to a database where several schemas with the same table structures exists, for example in a multi-tenant environment where each tenant has his own schema.

With a query like "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE COUNTRY = ${country-parameter}" the datasource will return different datasets based on which tenant performs the query. The sum of "connection-hash", "query-name" and "parameter used in the query" now forms a unique identifier that we can use to store and later lookup the resultset from the cache.

Comment: ok make sense. so in my case, I have only one DataSource defined and application as well as pentaho reporting module gets connection from it as and when needed. for pentaho reporting module, I have defined my own implementation of ConnectionProvider named "DataSourceConnectionProvider". and I am injecting datasource object  to this class through Spring configuration. so getConnection() method will return new connection from this DataSource. I also has only one schema per database. so should I only store datasource object in ArrayList and return it from getConnectionHash() method?

Comment: In the list return whatever you injected via spring. The objects you return in the arraylist must properly implement the "equals" and "hashcode" methods or you will see errors in the caching.

Comment: Thank you for detailed information about this method and its implementation. btw, where do I get the javadoc for different pentaho releases? actually I could not find details you explained in javaDoc for this Interface.